# Why am I getting Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025 when passing Method to where?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

I have a method that takes a generic TEntity which is overriden. It's signature is as follows:

```
public virtual Expression<Func<AclProject, bool>> ProjectFilter(params TEntity[] objs)
    {
        return (p) => objs.Select(o => o.ID).Contains(p.ID);
    }
```

I then filter a query based on this:

```
from p in db.SomeDbSet where db.AclProjects.Where(ProjectFilter(p)).Any() select p
```

This results in a 1025 error. (note that it doesn't matter what the body of the ProjectFilter is, the error still occurs.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Not many people will be challenged to analyze unfinished code. Try to return something meaningful first.

Comment: Like what did I miss? I can't provide the real code, thus I wrote a sample that reproduces the issue. The body of Project Filter is a simple one line (p) => p.X = obj.X and nothing more.